# Efficiently find point of insertion for new point in list of clockwise sorted points (around a central point)

Tags: list, sorting, geometry, trigonometry

Imagine I have an ordered list of points, arranged around a central point.

I have a new point which I want to include in the list, but maintain the clockwise order around the central point.

The most obvious solution would be to find the angle between the centre and the new point, loop through the list, calculate the angle between each point and the centre to find the point of insertion, but I believe there is a better way that doesn't require using trigonometry (Math.atan2).

I came across a helpful sorting algorithm that manages to faultlessly sort an array of points around a central point using cross products, but I don't know how to rework this for my problem:

```
public class Vector2ClockwiseComparer : IComparer<Vector2>
{
    public Vector2 center;

    public Vector2ClockwiseComparer(Vector2 center)
    {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public int Compare(Vector2 v0, Vector2 v1)
    {
        if (v0.x - center.x >= 0 && v1.x - center.x < 0)
            return 1;
        if (v0.x - center.x < 0 && v1.x - center.x >= 0)
            return -1;

        if (v0.x - center.x == 0 && v1.x - center.x == 0) {
            if (v0.y - center.y >= 0 || v1.y - center.y >= 0)
                if (v0.y > v1.y)
                    return 1;
                else return -1;
            if (v1.y > v0.y)
                return 1;
            else return -1;
        }

        // compute the cross product of vectors (CenterPoint -> a) x (CenterPoint -> b)
        var det = (v0.x - center.x) * (v1.y - center.y) -
                            (v1.x - center.x) * (v0.y - center.y);
        if (det < 0)
            return 1;
        if (det > 0)
            return -1;

        // points a and b are on the same line from the CenterPoint
        // check which point is closer to the CenterPoint
        var d1 = (v0.x - center.x) * (v0.x - center.x) +
                        (v0.y - center.y) * (v0.y - center.y);
        var d2 = (v1.x - center.x) * (v1.x - center.x) +
                        (v1.y - center.y) * (v1.y - center.y);
        if (d1 > d2)
            return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

Another way of visualizing the problem is to imagine looping through the list as sequential pairs of points, and asking if the new point is positioned in the eyeline of  infinite frustrum formed from these 2 points and the central point (the eye), but is it possible to do that without trigonometry?

Comment: You can use this comparator to find the insertion index with binary search, just as one would normally do with scalars. `Atan` is definitely overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCW (counterclockwise/clockwise direction) function based on cross product (you already have `det`) and implement a kind of binary search.

The simplest way I see to avoid cyclic problems is introduction of two fictive points P[M] - mirror of P[0] against the center and P[N+1] - copy of the first point in the end of list. Insert them once and correct M index when needed.

Find CCW for the first and new point. If it is True, make binary search in range `0..M`, and after insertion increment M. In case of False make binary search in range `M..N+1`

Comment: The solution is more complicated than that, because of the cyclic geometry.